# Is there an iOS app to display several offline raster maps with transparency?

Tags: raster, layers, ios, iphone, offline

There are several iPhone apps displaying offline maps.
Some of them can show custom maps, for instance loaded as MBTiles or sqlite files.

[Galileo-app](http://galileo-app.com/) does this pretty well.

But it is only possible to display **only one** tiled map at a time. 
I need to display **several tiled raster layers** (say 3 or 4) with a **transparency** (for instance with an opacity control slider for each layer).

My rasters are hand drawn tracks (black 'wire' on white/transparent background), old maps tiles and openstreetmap tiles. Goal: find my way by crossing information from those georeferenced maps.

[TiledMap app](http://wildmansoftware.com/) looks to be doing this, but is missing from iTune (dev account not renewed).

Is there any iOS app doing this? (Otherwise I would have to code one, but this is too much work)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Collector for ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/apps/collector) supports maps with multiple tiled layers.  It currently doesn't have offline maps but that will be supported in an [update being released](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/15/collector-with-disconnected-editing-is-coming-soon/) this month.

Comment: Thanks. It looks interesting but I'm an individual producing a couple of maps for a bunch of friends, so the business model is not adapted as I understand it (yearly subscription + fees...) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you use ArcGIS, you could try [**CarryMap**](http://www.dataeast.com/en/CarryMap.asp). It is a software tool to export a map from *ArcGIS* to a mobile device. It supports multiple raster layers.

Although you *cannot alter* the transparency of layers on the mobile device, their *transparency is preserved*. So if the corresponding ArcGIS raster layers had a transparency setting, the raster is shown with the same transparency in mobile view. This enables you to overlay multiple raster layers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried GIS 2go ([www.gis2go.com](http://www.gis2go.com)). We support offline maps for ArcGIS Desktop (I suppose we are biased, as we developed it, but maybe it fits for your purpose)